# Can the Kinect 360 + adapter be used in the same way?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to decide between a Kinect 360 + an adapter or a Kinect for Windows v1 for my project.

Can the Kinect 360 be used in the same way as Kinect for Windows through the SDK?

I will be mainly working with websockets for a web app.

Comment: For a web app? You mean accessing a Kinect attached to the machine that's running the browser? That may not be possible - I'd be surprised if it were possible to access a remote Kinect without a client-side component. (But that's a different question than recommending which Kinect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the kinect 360 can be accessed through the v1.8 SDK. The difference is that you aren't allowed to use the kinect 360 in a commercial project.